# Integration Testing With @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this test in my project:

```
@DataJpaTest
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:local-configuration.properties")
public class CanPixaRepositoryTest  {

    @Autowired
    private CanPixaRepository canPixaRepository;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testAll() {
        canPixaRepository].getAvui("fqs");
    }
}
```

local-configuration.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

but when I run the test, canPixaRepositoryRepository is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spring boot applications, the simplest approach is using @DataJpaTest with H2 to test your repositories if you are using JPA and Spring Data JPA.

1. Add h2 dependency into your test scope. Spring Boot will auto-configure it and use it to replace the runtime DataSource in the testing phase.
2. Annotate your tests with `@DataJpaTest`. Then the `EntityManager`, your repositories, and a test-purpose `TestEntityManager` are available in the Spring Application Context.

Check [my example here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-webmvc-jwt-sample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/demo/VehicleJpaTest.java).

(Spring 5/Spring Boot 2 added Junit 5 support, it does not require the `@Runwith` or `@Extendwith` if you are using Junit 5 integration, the DataJpaTest itself is a meta-annotation, before Spring 2.4, to enable Junit5, you have to exclude JUnit 4 from spring-boot-test and add JUnit 5 manually. In the upcoming Spring Boot 2.4, JUnit 5 is the default test runner)

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootTest` annotation is used to setup the entire application context while the `@DataJpaTest` will setup the application context so that you could test your jpa related code, it will setup a slice of your application context for this specific use case .So there is no need to use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation with `@DataJpaTest`, use it like :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:local-configuration.properties")
public class CanPixaRepositoryTest  {

    @Autowired
    private CanPixaRepository canPixaRepository;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testAll() {
        canPixaRepository.getAvui("fqs");
    }
}
```

Since SpringBoot 2.1 you don't have to provide the `@ExtendWith`annotation to tell Junit to enable spring support as it is already provided with the annotations like `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest`.